# Facebook app request without requesting permissions

Tags: ios, facebook

I make a facebook app request from my iOS app. When facebook user gets my request notification and clicks it facebook shows permission dialog. But I don't need any permissions. I want user to simply go to my website to download the app. Is it possible to disable the permission dialog and go straight to my website?

Comment: Do you by any change have “Authenticated Referrals” set up in your app’s settings …?

Comment: Yes, I do. You saved my day! Please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Posted as an answer. (And elaborated on the topic a bit more, for future readers benefit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to disable the permission dialog and go straight to my website?

Do you by any change have [Authenticated Referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals) set up in your app’s settings …?

These are a mechanism provided by Facebook, to ensure all users arriving at your app from links inside Facebook will be already authenticated, by asking them to log in and accept specified permissions, before they get to your app.

If you don’t want users to be bothered by that, because either you do not need them to be connected/accept permissions, or want to do login later on and trigger it yourself – then just turn Authenticated Referrals off in your app settings.